# Discord Bot Creation for a Beginner

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.io

I have never coded a Discord Bot before but am familiar with Javascript so I figured I would give it a shot. I used the beginner files from this site [Digital Trends](https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/) but am running into some issues.

I have the bot running in my server and the basic command swapped from "!" to "?" and the included command "?ping" does return the expected response "Pong!"

I run a server where we start a video game each month and play through while discussing it along the way, similar to a book club. So I'm trying to create a channel where people can suggest a game using a bot command since I don't trust they could handle following simple rules on their own.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to go about taking a user command of:

`?gs "Video Game Title" "Platform"`

And having the bot delete the command and repost as:

> @user suggested **Video Game Title** for **Platform**

While also adding reaction emojis "" and "" to allow other users to vote.

I'm not asking for anyone to do this for me, but to simply help point me in the right direction of how to code this with Discord in mind using JS (if possible)

Here is my current "bot.js" code:

```js
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '?') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: well parse your message to retrieve the values you want (your game title and your platform) would be the first step... and adding the gs command to your switch case.
Well basically at least give it a try no? this is just the base code

Comment: This is true, this is all the base -- everything I have tried has broken it. I'm either not reading the "How-to" articles well enough, or my knowledge of JS has slipped so much I just can't comprehend it anymore.

Comment: I have no experience in coding Discord bot, but I see a `args = args.splice(1)` before the `switch` statement. You should log this variable to see what's inside.

Comment: then you should read some string manipulation in JS, because that is it basically. You have your full message, you need to parse it so you retrieve your variables that you will use later.
This will be your first step. After that, well it is related to discord bot code and I don't really have any experience

Answer (score 0):

```js
args = args.splice(1);
```

This line is incorrect, `args` (being a string) has no `.splice()` method. (I often get `.slice()` and `.split()` confused, so this happens to me a lot too!)

Instead, use:

```js
args = args.split(" ").slice(1);
```